# How to check in checkout page that is user already registered in magento?

Tags: magento, checkout

User will provide his email address in checkout page. And I will have to identify that is user already registered or not. If he is registered then he will asked to enter his password to login else he will get the registration form.
How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here given a sample code

**in  phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    oData.email = 'customeremail@domain.com';
    jQuery.ajax({
                url:postUrl,
                type: "POST",
                data: oData,
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {                    
                    // here enable the password enter text field
                }
            });
</script>>
```

**in ajax controller**

```
public function checkCustomerExistAction()
{       

    if ($this->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        echo 'Ajax Expired'; 
        return;
        $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        // here check the customer exist or not
        if ($customer->getId()) {

                echo $customer->getId(); 
                // here you can use your own logic
            }
        else {

            echo '0'; 
        }
    }
}
```